# Paste not working between Excel and Word through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a workbook which creates Word reports based on a Word template and tables in the workbook.

Depending on the equipment type, it copies a range from the spreadsheet and pastes it to two bookmark locations in the word document (bmInternal and bmExternal). I tried using PasteAppendTable, but this only works once. If I try to use it twice, for each bookmark, it copies nothing both times. As such I used Paste for one and PasteAppendTable for the second (PasteAppendTable is much neater as the formatting is better).

This worked fine, but I made changes to the code, not related to this, and now the Paste (which goes to bmInternal) isn't working. I can't see why when I've not changed anything regarding that part:

```
Sub Data2Word()

Application.GoTo Reference:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

GoAgain:
On Error Resume Next
Dim vItem As String
'Dim vImagePath As String

Dim vCurrentRow As Integer

Dim vDesc As String
Dim vN2 As String
Dim vGuide As String
Dim vUnit As String
Dim vBlock As String

Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape
Dim rng As Excel.Range                    'our source range
Dim rngText As Variant
Dim rngText2 As Variant

Dim wdApp As New Word.Application   'a new instance of Word
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document          'our new Word template
Dim myWordFile As String            'path to Word template
Dim wsExcel As Worksheet
Dim tmpAut

'Find Item and type
vItem = ActiveCell.Value
vDesc = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
vN2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
vGuide = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
vBlock = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
vUnit = Left(vItem, 3)

If ActiveSheet.Range("rngREPORTED") = "Yes" Then
    MsgBox vItem & " already has a report."
    Exit Sub
End If
'initialize the Word template path
'here, it's set to be in the same directory as our source workbook
myWordFile = "W:\Entity\Inspect\WORD\INSPECTION TEMPLATES\Inspection Template - 20160511.dotx"

'open a new word document from the template
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(myWordFile)

If vGuide = "IGE01" Then

    rngText = "rngEXCH"
    rngText2 = "rngEXCHE"

ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(, 4) = "Mono" Then

    'Do Mono
    rngText = "rngMONO"

Else

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="rngItemSub", RefersTo:=Worksheets("SubEquipment").Range("B" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) & ":C" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6))

CarryOn:
        rngText = "rngItemSub"

End If

'Insert Tables
'get the range of the data

Set rng = Range(rngText)
rng.Copy                            'copy the range

wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmInternal").Range.Paste 'AppendTable

If vGuide = "IGE01" Then
    Set rng = Range(rngText2)
    rng.Copy
End If

wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmExternal").Range.PasteAppendTable

wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmItem").Range.InsertAfter vItem
wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmDesc").Range.InsertAfter vDesc
wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmN2").Range.InsertAfter vN2
wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmGuide").Range.InsertAfter vGuide
wdDoc.Bookmarks("bmBlock").Range.InsertAfter vBlock

wdDoc.Variables("wvItem").Value = vItem
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

With wdDoc
        Set wrdPic = .Bookmarks("bmImage").Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.7", Filename:="W:\Entity\Inspect\T&I\2016\Various Items\Photos\Sorted\" & vItem & ".pdf", LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
        wrdPic.ScaleHeight = 55
        wrdPic.ScaleWidth = 55
End With

wdApp.Visible = True

wdApp.Activate

wdDoc.SaveAs "W:\Entity\Inspect\WSDATA\REPORTS\2016\" & vUnit & "\" & vItem & " " & vN2 & " THO.docx" 'Mid(ActiveDocument.Name, 1, Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 4)

MoveHere:

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AllItems").Range("G" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = "Yes"
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: "Not working" is not sufficiently descriptive, please tell what error is thrown.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and see what it does. This tells it to just keep going if there's an error instead of pausing and notifying you.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct: ah!  yes, good idea!

Comment: Hi S Meaden.  There's no error.  It just doesn't paste anything as it's meant to.  Using PasteAppendTable twice, as I'd prefer to, makes both PasteAppendTable commands not work (as in not paste anything) too, which is why I use Paste once and PasteAppendTable once.

But now Paste doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think DocVariables are easier to use that Bookmarks.  Do a quick Google search on Word DocVariables.  Get things setup correct in Word, and then run the script below.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("FirstName").Value = Range("FirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("LastName").Value = Range("LastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("AnotherVariable").Value = Range("AnotherVariable").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```